# Need help importing data to new SQL server from MySQL folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, mysql, sql-server

My hard drive crashed, and can no longer write, but it can still read. Because of this, I was unable to export my SQL database to an .sql file for later importing. I can still access the drive, and install the mysql folder off of it, however, I do not know how I can import the data from that folder into my new MySQL server. What are the steps I can take to import this data?

The old system was Ubuntu 12.04, the new one is CentOS 5. The old system's drive is at home with me, however, the new system is a VPS located in a remote location. The old drive can not be booted either, due to the lack of writing ability.

**TLDR**: I need help importing data from an old database in the mysql folder into a new MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With both the old & new drives attached, issue the following command to dump the DB on the read-only disk:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --create-options -u root -p > /tempdir/dump.sql
```

where /tempdir/ is a temporary directory on the new (read-write) disk.

From here, you can reimport your data on the new MySQL instance by using the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql < /tempdir/dump.sql
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the new server is a VPS, so I don't have mysql on my windows desktop. Would it work if I did install mysql on my windows desktop?

Comment: If you have a shell access to the new server, simply copy the dump.sql file on the new server and issue the command above. If you don't have shell access, you had to install (on your PC) the client-side portion of mysql, to be able to connect to the new server via mysql protocol.

Comment: The VPS is in a remote location, I do not have access to the machinery, only over network. Therefore, I do not have a way to do mysqldump for the old database.

Comment: I edited the topic to be more clearer, I can not boot the old drive since it can not be written on.

Comment: 1) Can you access the old server and execute a mysqldump command? 2) Can you access the new server and execute a mysql import command? If you can't do n.1, well, you can't extract from the database. So you had to install, on your PC, the client portion of mysql, connect it to the old server (via TCP/IP), and execute the dump command. This will create a mysql dump on your Windows machine. After that, you had to do the same, reversed thing for the new server: connect to it and reload the dump file.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem. The best thing to do to recover the database is to launch a virtual image of the very same OS (Ubuntu 12.04), connect to it the old drive, copy the mysql folder in the virtual OS and launch the mysql process. At this point, you can follow the steps outlined before (mysqldump on the old database and mysql import on the new one).

Comment: I can not access the old server, only the drive that contains the files (the old server was localhosted). I can access the new server and execute a mysql import command.

Comment: See my comment above to how recover the old database...

Comment: Will try and update you on the process. I'm having issues with my new server as well, I'm assuming another failing hard drive, hence why I'm using a VPS.

Comment: I managed to get my new(er) server working just long enough to do a mysqldump, rsync the dump to the new server (CentOs) and import the dump. Thanks for all of your help!